# Nagios: fixing SSH error

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, nagios

I have installed Nagios with all needed packages. Everything seems to work normal but SSH connection fails. How should I fix that?

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't have an ssh server installed on your server, you have an ssh client installed.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Once installed, check your local firewall to see if connections are allowed

Answer (score 0):

Is sshd actually running?  I suspect it simply needs to be started.  Check 
netstat -an | grep 22 | grep LISTEN 
to confirm.